# What is the match/3 function in the context of the Phoenix Framework?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working through the Phoenix Framework documentation. In the [section about Routing](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/routing) there are a few mentions of the `match/3` function.

What is the `match/3` function? I've searched Google for a few things and can't find anything.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess they are referencing the private `match_route/4` function https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/7bbcd396f593f69fc941432d0eec5ef75d267479/lib/phoenix/router.ex#L325

It was previously called `match/4` but was changed in https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/6490f2ce0ec04693a0b4faf11039ae8d9e406dd3#diff-9a7a38188e7c9b90bc973ece4f731b21R313

I think this is what they mean because this is the function that the router macros compile down to, resulting in a series of function definitions that are pattern matched on when a request arrives.

See this slide https://speakerdeck.com/scrogson/taking-off-with-phoenix?slide=55 (and the previous slide) for an example of this expansion.

Answer (score 1):

> match(path, options, contents \ [])
>
> Main API to define routes.
>
> It accepts an expression representing the path and many options
>   allowing the match to be configured.

You can read more and see examples here:
[Phoenix Docs at DevDocs](https://devdocs.io/phoenix/plug/plug.router#match/3)

Just for reference, I usually have a lot of trouble using the search function in the Hex docs. I highly recommend to trying DevDocs for Elixir and Phoenix, their search function works quite better.

@Gazler is right, this function belongs to Plug. But this is the function the OP was looking for, right?

Comment: This is the function from Plug, not Phoenix. http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html#match/3